# Avraham's Converts

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, parashat-lech-lecha, abraham

In [Bereishis 12:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0112.htm#5) we see that Avraham took with him את הנפש אשר עשו בחרן "the soul they had made in Charan." Rashi there comments that "Abraham would convert the men, and Sarah would convert the women, and Scripture ascribes to them [a merit] as if they had made them".

Do we ever know what happened to this convert and what become of him?

Comment: This question sounds familiar.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31682/what-happened-to-avrahams-other-sons

Comment: @doubleAA nefesh can be plural as well - see bereishis 46:26-27

Comment: @YEZ I think that's a mass noun, not a plural

Comment: though wikipedia indicates it might be [plurative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singulative_number). hmmmm. I don't know if those are that different

Comment: @DoubleAA either way, wouldn't it amount to the same thing in the english representation?  Since it isn't a mass noun in English, wouldn't it be represented in plural?

Comment: @YEZ No... Mass nouns don't have to be plural. Besides that's talking about Gen46 not here.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm out of my grammatical depth here.  Could it not be a mass noun here, in which case the most accurate translation would be "souls?" If not, please explain, as I don't really know what I'm talking about.