# Abraham's converts.....to what?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, avot-patriarch-fathers, parashat-lech-lecha, abraham

Assuming the view that Avraham was not a Jew (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8646/5323) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/21913/5323)<sup>1</sup>), "ha-nefesh asher asu beCharan" (Gen. [12:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0112.htm#5)) that Rashi explains were converts, **what did they convert to?**

---

*To give credit where credit is due; my question was inspired by [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40577/5323).*

---

<sup>1</sup> *I'm using these as sources until I find better ones....if you can help me with this please comment!*

Comment: Noahidism or monotheism

Comment: this gives some perspective of what he did at first http://www.chabad.org/global/popup/default_cdo/aid/2615/jewish/Commentary.htm probably more to it though, he also had a yeshiva where he taught torah

Comment: Isn't the answer obvious?; Avraham came to believe in the One G'd; HaShem (Yud-Hey-Vav-Hey); so also the souls that came with him (seems to be people who could identify themselves with Avraham's way of life; and that's probably the reason the word for souls/persons is used here: nefesh).

Comment: In the Artscroll Bereishis Rabbah there are several insights on the topic of whether the Avos were considered Jewish or Bnei Noach. I don't have any of the volumes here, but if you have access to them you could take a look at their comments to this passuk and see if anything there helps.

Answer (score 2):

Avraham followed the faith of Shem and Ever. It was the same monotheism which had been transmitted by Adam in a continuous chain like is found in commentary of the Ohr HaChayim on Vayechi 49.

> והנכון בעיני הוא כי האבות קבלו התורה משם שקבל מנח שקבל מחנוך שקבל מאדם הראשון. אשר למדה מפי הגבורה דכתיב אז ראה וגו' ויאמר לאדם, (זהר ח"א קצט.) ושבאמצעותה צוהו לעבוד גן עדן וכמו שפירשתי בפסוק (לעיל ב' ט"ו) לעבדה ולשמרה. אך לא נצטוה אלא על ז' מצות שאם יעבור עליהם יהרג אבל שאר התורה קרוב לשכר אם יעשה ורחוק מן ההפסד אם לא יקיים,

This is also discussed in the beginning of Sefer Raziel HaMalach, Sefer Chanoch, Sefer Noach and is the subject of Sefer Yetzirah.

Starting particularly with the generation of Enosh, many people studied the traditions less and became confused. They started to believe in polytheism and to worship idols. This is also how it is explained by Rambam in chapter 1 of Hilchot Avodat Kochavim in the Mishnah Torah.

Comment: Rashb"i is quoted in the gemara as considering Sefer Chanoch to be a heretical work.

Comment: Citation? Although, just for the record, there are 3 other Seforim mentioned. And you are assuming whatever Sefer that may be referenced in your citation, if you have one, is the same Sefer Chanoch that I am bringing from.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just did a word search for "ספר חנוך" through both Shas Bavli & Yerushalmi and got zero hits.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt  if you would like a more accurate idea of Sefer Chanoch, check out Vol.1 of הספרים החיצונים by Avraham Kahane, the introduction 'על ספרות חנוך'.

Comment: And in keeping with that, Bereshit Rabbah, 25:1

Comment: Having read על ספרות חנוך, I feel my position remains tenable. FWIW, that Rashb"i is sourced from a good friend who is a talmid chacham (I'll ask for the mare makom). I chose to comment about Chanoch because as one may note it is mostly unextant in the Hebrew and Aramaic versions, although I would be very uncomfortable with anything which relies on a ספר חיצון in general, or an occult tradition which ws only written down in the time of the Rishonim (like ספר רזיאל המלאך)

Answer (score 0):

The most main stream view that I know of is that they converted to "Hebrew" Monotheism, because Avrahom was a Hebrew.

Comment: What do you mean avraham converted to hebrew i dont see any related hebrew as a relidlgion

Comment: Noachide "religion" with many other aspects of what would come to be Judaism, i.e. Bentching, morning prayers etc.,.